# Build request for postAction FosRestBundle WebTestCase

Tags: api, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm trying to make web test case for my restfull api app.

I'm using FosRestBundle and my problems is that I don't know how to build my request.

This is my fos-rest config:

```
fos_rest:
    disable_csrf_role: ROLE_API
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    format_listener: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            xml: true
            json : true
        templating_formats:
            html: true
        force_redirects:
            html: true
        failed_validation: HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
        default_engine: twig
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
```

This is my web test case :

```
    public function test_postAction()
        {
            $client = static::createClient();

            $parameters = [
                'contentText' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lobortis sapien ac magna hendrerit tincidunt. Nunc mi dui, rhoncus nec justo et, rutrum lobortis sem. Fusce venenatis orci nec sodales convallis. Nunc in quam a nibh semper convallis viverra ac augue.',
                'tasks' => [],
                'title' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            ];

            $url = $client
                ->getContainer()
                ->get('router')
                ->generate('post_note', [
                    '_format' => 'json',
                ])
            ;

            $client->request(
                'POST',
                $url,
                $parameters
            );
            $response = $client->getResponse();
        }
```

And my postAction method

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
    {

        try {
            $note = new Note();

            /** @var $form Form*/
            $form = $this->createForm(new NoteType(), $note);

            $this->removeExtraFields($request, $form);
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($note);
                $em->flush();

                return FOSView::create($note, Codes::HTTP_OK);
            }

            return FOSView::create(array('errors' => $form->getErrors()), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return FOSView::create($e->getMessage(), Codes::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

    }
```

The problem is that the condition $form->isValid() return false because all attributes of my object is null.

So I think I miss build my request because the $form->handleRequest($request) dosen't set attributes i've send to my object.

Do you have any idea why ? Do you know how to build my request ?

Thanks,
AlexL

Answer (score 0):

this might help and it is a snippet from a test I have that is 100% working.

```
    $crawler = $this->client->request(
        'POST'
        , '/api/validate'
        , []
        , []
        , [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
        ]
        , json_encode($data)
    );
```

$data being in your case $parameters. You shouldn't need the json_encode bit but it should work for you either way I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but nop it doesn't work... my parameters aren't assigned in my object :/